# Windows migration

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, workgroup

I need to migrate some workstation from a workrgroup based environment to a Windows 2008 domains.
I would'nt lose user profile, so is there some way to do that without migrating one-to-one by hand?

Answer (score 3):

[User State Migration Tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560801%28WS.10%29.aspx) is your friend in this case.